How to make the thumb of the scroll bar of fixed size?
I am building a custom scroll bar in my ReactJS application in which the thumb of the scroll bar is an image. Now when there is less content horizontally or vertically then the image is like kinda at the middle of the scrollbar as can be in the at[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TMaemAFJ.png)atched pictures as well.
Now I want that the custom image thumb should be the very start and end of the scrollbar just as if there were more content

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
